# Why my Roblox script doesn't work correctly

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I have problem with my lua script to roblox. Script has to firstly create team and add player to it. When the first player join to the game everything work correctly but if the second player join, then team will be created correctly but second player will be added to the first player's team.

```
local teamsFolder = game:GetService("Teams")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local team = Instance.new("Team")
    team.Name = player.Name
    team.Parent = teamsFolder
    team.AutoAssignable = false
    
    player.Team = team
end)
```

I also tried to replace 9 line for
`player.Team = teamsFolder[player.Name]`
but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each new Team needs a unique TeamColor:

```js
local teamsFolder,tab=game:GetService("Teams"),{}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local team,teamcolor=Instance.new("Team"),nil
    team.Name,team.AutoAssignable=player.Name,false
    repeat
        teamcolor=BrickColor.random()
    until not table.find(tab,teamcolor)
    table.insert(tab,teamcolor)
    team.TeamColor,team.Parent=teamcolor,teamsFolder
    player.Team=team
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    table.remove(tab,table.find(tab,player.TeamColor))
    teamsFolder[player.Name]:Remove()
end)
```